# Magento 2 - Change image role from DB

Tags: mysql, image, magento2

I need to change the image role (small,thumb,swatch,base) according to these requirements:

base image must take the value stored on swatch image

I found that the DB table where to do this, is **catalog_product_entity_varchar** which is composed by these columns:

"**attribute_id**" which contains the id of the attribute:

- base = 87
- small = 88
- thumb = 89
- swatch = 154

"**entity_id**" which contains the id of the product

"**value**" that contain the path to the image.
i.e. "/A/1/A1L6ON14_Timberland_T-Shirt_a_Maniche_Corte_Rosso-Z_1.jpg"

I need a query that
copy the column "value" from the "attribute_id"=154 only where the column "attribute_id"=87 for the "entity id"=xxx
(in this way I can test the query only for an unique product)

And a query that do the same, but on the whole table (without a specified entity id).

Comment: Make sure to check the attribute id's in the eav_attribute table. base/small/thumb was equal, but I had another ID for the swatch image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

update catalog_product_entity_varchar e1, catalog_product_entity_varchar e2
SET e1.value = e2.value
where e1.entity_id = e2.entity_id and e1.attribute_id = 87 and e2.attribute_id = 154 and e1.store_id = 32 and e2.store_id = 32;

update catalog_product_entity_varchar e1, catalog_product_entity_varchar e2
SET e1.value = e2.value
where e1.entity_id = e2.entity_id and e1.attribute_id = 87 and e2.attribute_id = 154 and e1.store_id = 33 and e2.store_id = 33;

update catalog_product_entity_varchar e1, catalog_product_entity_varchar e2
SET e1.value = e2.value
where e1.entity_id = e2.entity_id and e1.attribute_id = 87 and e2.attribute_id = 154 and e1.store_id = 0 and e2.store_id = 0;